# Getting from $\frac{x-4}{x-5}$ to $1+\frac{1}{x-5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Pretty embarrassing question lol.

> How do you get from $\;\dfrac{x-4}{x-5}\;$ to $\;1 + \dfrac{1}{x-5}\;$?

My calculus teacher did without explaining how, and its been 3 years since I took a non-stat focused class. Feel free to ridicule as necessary.

Comment: $$\frac {x-4}{x-5} = \frac {(x-5) + 1}{x-5} = 1 + \frac 1{x-5}$$

Comment: No ridicule, but note that this is considered an important transformation to be familiar with, and is often associated with the concept of "partial fractions."

Comment: This is a good way to reduce the degree of the numerator if it is larger than half that of the denominator.

Comment: More generally, suppose you have a 'linear fraction' $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$. If we ignore the $x$ terms, then we get $a/c$. Then $$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}-\frac{a}{c}=\frac{c(ax+b)-a(cx+d)}{c(cx+d)}=\frac{(bc-ad)}{c(cx+d)}=\frac{b-ad/c}{cx+d}, $$ or $$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\frac{c}{d}-\frac{b-ad/c}{cx+d}.$$ So one can always modify fractions in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have a rational function $$f(x) = \frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$$ so that the denominator polynomial is of degree no greater than the numerator polynomial: $\deg A \geq \deg B$.
This is the rational function equivalent of an "improper fraction".
For many purposes, particularly to calculate indefinite integrals, it can be useful to write this rational function as a sort of "mixed function" analogous to a mixed number via [polynomial division.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) "Improper" or not, *any* rational function $f(x)$ may always be uniquely expressed as $$f(x) = Q(x) + \frac{R(x)}{B(x)},$$ where $Q(x)$ is the quotient and $R(x)$ is the remainder when $A(x)$ is divided by $B(x)$. $R(x)$ is guaranteed to have degree strictly smaller than $B(x)$.
Once $f(x)$ is expressed in this form, it's much easier to antidifferentiate: $Q(x)$ can be very easily antidifferentiated using [Power Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule), and there exist various techniques (such as [partial fractions](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/partialfractions.aspx) and/or [inverse tangent substitution](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_211_Calculus_II/Chapter_5%3A_Integration/5.7%3A_Integrals_Resulting_in_Inverse_Trigonometric_Functions_and_Related_Integration_Techniques)) to compute $R(x)/B(x)$ in general.
This also explains where the [horizontal asymptote rule](https://www.softschools.com/math/calculus/finding_horizontal_asymptotes_of_rational_functions/) comes from: $f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote if and only if $Q(x)$ is a constant, which implies $\deg(A) \leq \deg(B)$.
If $\deg(A) = \deg(B)$, $Q(x)$ is the ratio of the leading coefficients; if $\deg(A) < \deg(B)$, then $Q(x) = 0$.

In the specific case you mention, long division is overkill. We notice by inspection that the numerator is just the denominator plus a constant: $$(x - 4) = (x - 5) + 1,$$ and as someone pointed out in the comments, the result simplifies to $$\frac{(x-4)}{(x-5)} = \frac{(x-5)}{(x-5)} + \frac{1}{x - 5} = 1 + \frac{1}{x-5},$$ which is very easy to antidifferentiate using the [natural log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm).